# Virsh console not responding after rebooting guest machine

Tags: kvm-virtualization, console, virsh

I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04 with KVM. Whenever I install a guest VM (CentOS 7 or Fedora 34), virsh console works fine in the beginning. However, when I reboot this VM, virsh console stops working.

Does anybody know what's going wrong in this case?

Comment: Did you configure the guest to use a serial console?

Comment: I guess yes since I can connect through it in the beginning. The problem arises when I reboot the guest (or the host) machine. For instance, this is how I create one VM: virt-install --name VMMysql --memory 8192 --disk pool=default,size=32 --vcpus 2 --location /home/bopuser/isos/Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-34-1.2.iso --os-variant=fedora3 --console pty,target.type=virtio --graphics none --check disk_size=off

Comment: This does not configure the guest OS!

Comment: But how can I connect in the beginning?